# Why does div with content inside have automatic margin?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know why a `margin` appears to be present when there is content (paragraph, etc) in the `<div>`?

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
.container2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

In the example above, there is a margin between the two `<div>`s, but if I take out the paragraph, the `margin` is gone.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Paragraphs have built in margin and margins collapse.

Answer (score 1):

Because some of HTML tags have default margin, `<p>` included, and it collapses. Usual approach is to use [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/) to style websites **exactly** as you want them to look.

Answer (score -1):

You can remove all margins from all elements by doing something like this within your CSS, with the * targeting all elements:

```
*{margin:0px;}
```

That is probably a bit extreme and you'll be best off finding a proven CSS reset template to follow.  I've had luck using one I found online years ago.  They did the basic reset like this (to selectively remove whatever elements they wanted:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Keep in mind you'll end up having to put back in a lot of margins you want if you go with either of these methods, but it will remove the margin you are looking to target.

Hope it helps!